# How can I prevent HttpClient via IHttpClientFactory from logging to ILogger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am writing a custom `ILoggerProvider` which forwards log messages over HTTP using an `HttpClient` instance obtained via the configured `IHttpClientFactory`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
}
```

When my `ILoggerProvider` forwards a batch of logs, its `HttpClient` generates additional log messages, which then get forwarded... resulting in a stack overflow of sorts.

How can I suppress **only** the messages that are generated within the limited scope of the method that performs the forwarding, so that I can filter out logs from `HttpClient` or anything else that might be logging during that scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named instances of `HttpClient` created via `IHttpClientFactory` use [log categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#logging) containing those names. Logs sent to this forwarding provider can then be filtered out.

If a named `HttpClient` is created like this:

```
httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(MyForwardingLoggerProvider))))
```

Then one possible way to filter out the logs is to return a "no-op" instance when this `HttpClient` instance attempts to create an `ILogger` with the provider name in the `categoryName`:

```
ILogger ILoggerProvider.CreateLogger(String categoryName)
{
    if (categoryName.StartsWith($"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.{nameof(MyForwardingLoggerProvider)}."))
    {
        // Ignores all logs
        return NoopLogger.Instance;
    }
    else
    {
        // Performs log forwarding
        return new MyForwardingLogger(categoryName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am writing a custom ILoggerProvider which forwards log messages over HTTP using an HttpClient instance obtained via the configured IHttpClientFactory:

Just don't do that, use another HttpClient that isn't tied to the factory.

Comment: Exactly, the OP essentially has circular dependencies here. ILogger uses IHttpClientFactory, which uses ILogger, which use IHttpClientFactory, ad infinitum.